# Wireless network animation on OPNET

Tags: networking, simulation, wireless

when i set up a wireless scenario and record packet flows , then run the simulation and then play 2D animation the packet flow is not visible although its visible in case of any wired network , so is there any needed configuration to make packet flow visible ?

Answer (score 0):

Modeler does not provide wireless packet animation using 2D animation. Best way to do is to run simulation in debug mode. In the debug mode, you can see the packet transmission in wireless link. like a ripple.